# How to include app link in Facebook share dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I am writing am app with Ionic/Cordova and using a Facebook plugin from here:

https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

I created an app link using the [Facebook Tools](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host) and then passed the URL (e.g. fb.me/1234567890) to the Facebook Share Dialog as the contentURL.

This works well in the browser, but fails on iOS - the Share Dialog appears but there is just an infinite spinner in it and the posted text never gets to Facebook. If I use any other non-AppLink URL, the Share Dialog works just fine.

This worked in the past using Cordova 3.x and the WizCorp Facebook plugin but with all the upgrades, perhaps a requirement has changed that I cannot find?

Comment: Can you setup a page for us to reproduce? Can you show the exact AppLink you are using?

Comment: Our app is mobile-only and we use a few different app links to deep link. Here is a simple one that used to work before the upgrade: https://fb.me/890681247655434